# Uso VsCode con Python y actualmente no me deja ejecutar ningún código 2

Tags: python, vscode, terminal

Primeramente disculpen el desorden de la publicación anterior; le resumo nuevamente mi problema con más orden y detalle

Actualmente estoy comenzando con Python, uso VsCode; no había tenido ningún problema, hasta el día de ayer.

Básicamente el problema es que puedo ejecutar líneas de código de forma individual (con "shift+Enter") y funcionan, pero en el momento que decido ejecutar todo a la vez, recibo un error

Por otro lado, si ejecuto todo el código primero, con el botón que aparece en la esquina superior derecha de VsCode, corre bien el codigo; pero si intento ejecutar líneas de código de forma individual (con "shift+Enter"), también me funcionan, pero cuando vuelvo a ejecutar todo el código, recibo el error

La secuencia de como hago las cosas va a así:

1-Abro cualquier archivo

2-escribo algo simple

sentence_1="tres tristes tigres tragaban trigo en un trigal"

print(sentence_1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3-Ejecuto linea por linea con "Shift+Enter" y en la terminal sale como debería

"Shift+Enter" para sentence_1="tres tristes tigres tragaban trigo en un trigal"

> > sentence_1="tres tristes tigres tragaban trigo en un trigal"

"Shift+Enter" para print(sentence_1)

> > tres tristes tigres tragaban trigo en un trigal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4-Intento Ejecutar el código completo con el botón que aparece en la esquina superior de VsCode, y en la terminal me aparece

> > > & C:/Users/LEROLERO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/LEROLERO/Desktop/Untitled-1.py
> > > File "", line 1
> > > & C:/Users/LEROLERO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/LEROLERO/Desktop/Untitled-1.py
> > > ^
> > > SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5-En la pestaña de problemas Desde que abro el VsCode, tengo esto:

Missing module docstring

Module name "Untitled-1" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style

Constant name "sentence_1" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style

Final newline missing

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las extensiones que tengo instaladas actualmente son:

-Python

-Pylint

-Pylance

-Jupyter Keymap

-Jupyter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se ve mi barra de estado, Donde se evidencia que utilizo Python 3.10.6 de 64Bits

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuevamente, insisto que estaría infinitamente agradecido si me ayudan a solucionar este problema que me mantiene atado de manos

---Actualización---

Conseguí un video que le mandé a un amigo, donde le mostraba algo que había hecho; lo que logre notar es que seguramente el problema tenga algo de relacion, con la dirección que aparece justo después de ejecutar el codigo

Actualmente lo que me aparece es esto

PS C:\Users\LEROLERO.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher> & C:/Users/LEROLERO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/LEROLERO/Desktop/Untitled-1.py

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el video que les comento, me aparecía de dirección esto

C:\Users\LEROLERO> & C:/Users/LEROLERO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/LEROLERO/Desktop/NOMBRE_DE_ARCHIVO.py"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema viene de allí, debo restaurar esa dirección que tenia por defecto, por favor si alguien tiene alguna idea de como modificarla

Comment: No se nada de VSCode, pero NO creo que el interprete de Python pueda abrir un .py con comandos como "$ elarchivo.py"

Comment: Oprime Ctrl + Shift + B, esto lo que hace es que te permite elegir con qué va a compilar/ejecutar el código. Lo que podría estar pasando es que por alguna razón cambiaste la configuración de como se ejecutan los archivos de Python y por eso ahora esté utilizando algo diferente.

Comment: Sugiero desinstales python y lo vuelvas a instalar, como debe ser. (1) Desinstalar python. (2) Ir a [Variables de Entorno](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+variables+de+entorno+path) y en PATH verificar y eliminar cualquier referencia de Python que haya quedado. (3) Ejecutar el setup -> clic "Add Python to PATH", clic "Customize installation" -> Next -> clic "Install for all users" y abajo donde está la ruta de instalación, colocarla en raíz del disco C:\Python310 -> clic "Install".

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que, debido a que has usado Shift+Enter para ejecutar las líneas de una en una, en la terminal se te ha abierto un intérprete Python interactivo (es lo que VSCode hace la primera vez que pulsas Shift+Enter, arranca un intérprete Python interactivo y luego se limita a "enviarle" la línea a ejecutar, básicamente copiando esa línea y pegándola en la terminal en la que ya está abierto el intérprete).

Puedes comprobar que efectivamente la terminal está ejecutando un intérprete porque tiene la cadena ">>>" como *prompt*.

Cuando después intentas ejecutar el programa pulsando el triángulo "Play", lo que hace VSCode es enviar a la terminal una cadena con el comando python seguido del nombre de fichero. En concreto, en tu caso, la cadena enviada es:

```
& C:/Users/LEROLERO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/LEROLERO/Desktop/Untitled-1.py
```

Esa cadena está pensada para que sea ejecutada por un intérprete de comandos del sistema, pero en la terminal lo que tienes es el intérprete Python, que lo que espera es una línea válida de Python, pero no es lo que recibe y de ahí el error. Puedes ver en la captura de pantalla que tú mismo incluyes cómo el error es producido por el intérprete interactivo, pues es visible el prompt `>>>`.

La solución es asegurarse de que en la terminal que tienes abierta *no haya un intérprete python*. Esto puedes hacerlo dando por terminado el intérprete que habías lanzado al principio escribiendo dentro de la terminal `quit()` y pulsando enter, o bien abriendo una nueva terminal con el botón `+` que hay en la terminal (o con la combinación de teclas Ctrl+Ñ)

### Bonus

Lo que ves en la pestaña "problemas" no tiene relación en realidad con el error que estabas obteniendo. Son recomendaciones sobre cómo mejorar tu código. Aunque no tiene nada qué ver con tu problema, te "traduzco" lo que VSCode te indica que puede ser mejorado:

- Añadir documentación (escribir un *docstring* al inicio de tu fichero explicando para qué sirve)
- Elegir un mejor nombre para el fichero en el que guardar el código, que por defecto se llama `Untitled-1.py`, y para mejor seguir las convenciones python debería llamarse `untitled_1.py`
- Renombrar tu variable como `SENTENCE_1`. Esta sugerencia te la hace porque, a la vista de tu código, parece que esa variable es en realidad una constante (pues nunca cambia de valor), de modo que te sugiere escribirla en mayúsculas que es como se suelen escribir las constantes en python.
- Añadir una línea al final del fichero.

Comment: super agradecido por la información brindada, me saco varias dudas que tenía; ahora me gustaría saber si es posible "reconectar" o "iniciar nuevamente" el interprete una vez utilizado el comando "Exit()"

Me gustaría saber si eso es posible pues al usar "exit()" ya no me permite ejecutar líneas de codigo de forma individual, me aparece: 

"no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de 
script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo"

Comment: No puedes "reconectar" a un intérprete una vez cerrado. Para ese caso lo mejor es no cerrarlo, sino abrir una terminal nueva con el botón `+`. Entonces podrás cambiar de una terminal a otra con los pequeños iconos que contienen un `>` al lado de la terminal. Una de las terminales será un "shell" normal, en el que podrás lanzar python para el programa completo. La otra será la que contiene el intérprete en ejecución para que funcione Shift-enter. Deberás cambiar de una a otra según lo que quieras hacer. El botón "play" de todas formas no funcionará hasta que no cierres con quit() el intérprete

Answer (score 1):

Python funciona gracias a un intérprete, que es un programa que corre en segundo plano para procesar el código que le mandes.

Esto significa que cada vez que corres un código de Python, el computador va a donde está python.exe lo abre, lo ejecuta y le pasa tu código línea por línea.

#### Primera opción

Normalmente el proceso es:

1. Presionas botón de ejecutar código entero.
2. Computador abre/ejecuta python.exe
3. escribe tu código en la consola python.exe linea por linea.
4. fin, se cierra python.exe

#### Segunda opción

Pero como en jupyter notebook, surgió la necesidad de no cerrar el intérprete python.exe
El proceso es:

1. Se abre python.exe
2. Espera por cada línea de código que mandes
3. No hay fin, hasta que cierres manualmente python.exe

El problema tuyo es que estás intentando hacer las dos al mismo tiempo con el mismo python.exe

#### Solución

Para salirte del segundo manualmente, debes escribir `exit()` en el python.exe
Luego sí te dejará correr normal.

---

La segunda opción es más para un entorno de jupyter donde vas corriendo celdas aisladas... Si lo estás usando para depurar código es mejor usar "F5" o en ejecutar/Iniciar depuración.

Tip: usa `# %%` para separar por celda si te gusta usar la segunda opción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes asegurar que tengas el intérprete correcto, ya que si has instalado un *virtual environment*, VSCode opta por el intérprete por default, entonces asegura que tengas el intérprete con:

> 'Ctrl + Shift + P'

Extiendes la paleta de comandos y puedes escribir Python para seleccionar el intérprete que desees.

Y por lo General para debugger un código en VSCode usas:

> F5 y 'Ctrl + F5'

para ejecutar.

Los problemas que te aparecen son extensiones o más bien de módulos que son guías de estilo para codificar de manera limpia y entendible

Comment: Hola el_xino, gracias por tu interés, pero te sugiero que no malgastes tu tiempo, estás contestando una pregunta hecha hace cuatro meses, y que para más INRI, ya tiene una respuesta aceptada.

Comment: Gracias, no me di cuenta, soy relativamente nuevo y me estoy familizarizandome con la plataforma.

Comment: Bienvenido/a el_xino; para notar cuándo se hizo la pregunta, puedes ver la fecha arriba del nombre de usuario autor de tal pregunta, en la esquina inferior derecha de ella. Por cierto @MarcePuente, esta pregunta aún no tiene respuestas aceptadas. E INRI para este caso es en minúsculas ;) No es malo responder a preguntas luego de mucho tiempo, siempre y cuando estas últimas hayan sido bien formuladas y realmente merezcan ser respondidas.

Comment: @padaleiana, tienes razón, pero solo en parte, si miras los comentarios en la respuesta de abufalia, verás que el OP, "agradece", lo que indica que la repuesta es correcta, de ahí mi observación, igual gracias por estar atenta.

Comment: @MarcePuente Ojo que aceptar una respuesta es indicar que la respuesta fue _la más útil_ para OP, no siempre es una respuesta correcta (aunque en este caso, sí). Pueden haber varias respuestas correctas en una pregunta, todas útiles.

Comment: @padaleiana, cuando tienes razón tienes razón!!.